# Access-Control-Allow-Origin from mobile devices

Tags: ajax, angularjs, http, cors

We currently have an API running on a cluster of servers, with Apache. Every response from the API is JSON.

I've been playing around with the http://ionicframework.com/ framework, which uses Angular JS as it's Javascript base. It's got to the point where I want to make requests from the web app I'm working on, with Angular:

```
$http.get('http://myapi.com/getData').success(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

Now of course, I get the error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://myapi.com/getData. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8100' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Now this is obviously a CORS issue, and I understand why. One solution for this would be to set `Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"` on the servers, however opening up the entire API to any cross site request is surely risky?

Instead, is there no way for me to set some form of key/security which the server checks against to make sure it's coming from the app I'm building.

The angular $http docs have:

```
xsrfHeaderName – {string} – Name of HTTP header to populate with the XSRF token.
xsrfCookieName – {string} – Name of cookie containing the XSRF token.
```

Where would I check for these on the server, and what is a secure way of doing this?

JSONP is not an option, since the API can't be changed in it's current state.

Comment: Could you not use CORS with a specific site, rather than `*`? `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://example.com`. (Obviously you are currently running this on your local machine: there will obviously be a different domain on your actual site.)

Comment: The issue is, there is no specific domain. Ionic is a web app framework, so the request will be coming from a mobile phone.

Comment: How you solve this error?